# Is supertest compatible with express.js 2.5.8?

Tags: testing, express, jasmine, jasmine-node, supertest

I am using express.js version 2.5.8 (from legacy code) and am looking to test route loading using supertest. I am having an issue with the server running, but not stopping. I run my tests using `jasmine-node`, which indicates that my assertion succeeds. However, the console shows that the process is still running.

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , express = require('express');

describe('Example Test', function() {
  var app;

  beforeEach(function() {
    app = express.createServer();

    app.configure(function() {
      app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
      app.use(express.logger('dev'));
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.send(200);
    });
  });

  it('index should return 200', function(done) {
    request(app)
    .get('/')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      expect(err).toBe(null);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This example is adapted from one likely using express.js 3.x.x. My assumption is that the express server behaves differently, leading to it not closing when the request terminates inside the test. I am uncertain how to correct this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is still running because you aren't closing it anywhere. Just add `app.close()` to your `end(function(){})` to stop the express server. If you also want to exit from node use `process.exit()`.

Comment: Thank you kindly, @zeMirco. I could swear I had already tried this solution. Indeed I did have `app.close()` in there at one point. Though, it must not have been in the correct location.